# Change default annotation author in PDF Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, pdf

I wish to change the default annotation author to "anonymous" so that whenever I add an annotation, the name "anonymous" would appear.

Trying to follow the steps provided here: https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/annotation-properties.html.en

I am using document viewer 3.28.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.03. Right clicking on the annotation icon does not show Annotation properties as stated in the link. I can however right click on each and every single annotation I make and change the author for that annotation, but just wondering if there is a more effective way. I do not wish to change each one separately.

Comment: The page you linked to says "there is no way to save different default settings for annotation properties, at this time." What you want to do isn't possible.

Comment: Note that this is not possible with the PDF viewer evince, but is possible with the Okular PDF viewer. See documentation https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/okular/okular/annotations.html "The newly constructed annotation will have as author the author you set in the Annotations page in Okulars configuration dialog."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily set the author to whatever you want in Settings > annotations. From the manual:

> The newly constructed annotation will have as author the author you
> set in the Annotations page in Okulars configuration dialog. The
> Annotations page can also be used to configure the content of the
> annotating toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Evince/Document Viewer picks author name from the Username of the Ubuntu session.
Either change one by one when adding a Note or Highlight Text, or temporarily change the session name in Ubuntu Settings.
There is also a python code that can change all Notes/HiText to a particular name or blank.
Here:
https://gist.github.com/wecacuee/f1e92d421312b7c7c1907667f4f3a318